# How to produce a ggvis plot similar to this ggplot2 one

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

I'm familiar with ggplot2, here is the ggplot2 code for producing what I want:

```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(scales)
   set.seed(100)
   df <- data.frame(t = rep(seq(from=as.POSIXct('00:15:00',format='%H:%M:%S'),
                             to=as.POSIXct('24:00:00',format='%H:%M:%S'),by='15 min'),times=2),
                     y = c(rnorm(96,10,10),rnorm(96,40,5)),
                     group = factor(rep(1:2,each=96)),
                     type = factor(rep(1:3,each=64)))

  ggplot(data=df,aes(x=t,y=y,col=type))+geom_point(aes(size=type))+
  geom_line(aes(group=group))+
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format('%H:%M', tz = "Asia/Taipei"),
                   breaks = date_breaks('2 hours'))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('red','blue','green'))
```

[image]

This plot takes line group, line type, point color, point size and x-axis time format into consideration. I want to produce a similar plot just like this with `ggvis` and use `add_tooltip` to display the point's information (all variables) when hovering. But I found it hard to specify the blue, red and green colour. The `ggvis`
code that I tried is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(df,id=1:nrow(df))
    ggvis(data=df,x=~t,y=~y,stroke=~group) %>% 
      layer_points(fill=~type,size=~type, key:=~id, fillOpacity := 0.5,
                   fillOpacity.hover := 0.8,size.hover := 500) %>% 
      scale_nominal("size", range = c(50,200)) %>%
      layer_lines() %>% 
      add_tooltip(all_values,'click') %>%
      add_legend(scales=c("fill","size"), properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 150))) %>%
      set_options(duration = 0) %>% 
      add_axis(type="x",format="%H:%M")
```

Could someone offer me some help?

Comment: Can you at least show the code for your `ggvis` attempt? It would likely be easier to start with that than start from scratch.

Comment: Do you need to use `ggvis`?  I find it easier to add tooltips to existing `ggplot` code with the `ggraph` package.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I've post the ggvis code that I tried. But I think that code is far from what I desire.

Comment: @DavidKlotz Thank you for your suggestion. I'd like to use `ggvis`. But I will try `ggraph` if it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is my replication of your ggplot2 graph:

```
ggvis(data=df,x=~t,y=~y,opacity=~group,stroke=~type) %>% 
  layer_points(fill=~type,size=~type, key:=~id, fillOpacity := 0.5,fillOpacity.hover := 0.8,size.hover := 500) %>% 
  layer_lines() %>%
  scale_nominal("size", range = c(50,200)) %>%
  add_tooltip(all_values,'click') %>%
  add_legend(scales=c("fill","size"), properties = legend_props(legend = list(y = 150))) %>%
  set_options(duration = 0) %>% 
  add_axis(type="x",format="%H:%M") %>%
  scale_ordinal("fill", range = c("red", "blue", "green")) %>%
  scale_ordinal("stroke", range = c("red", "blue", "green")) %>%
  scale_ordinal("opacity", range = c(1, 1))
```

[click to see my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4mUH.png)

Note that to perfectly replicate your original plot, I add a auxiliary mapping to opacity to set the lines apart while keeping stroke mapping to type

Comment: I just noticed this question is long-overdue, but if you think my answer helps you or matches your question, please accept it. It would worth my time. Thank you